# javascript push result in main function argument for confirmation use

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, confirm

Sorry for the question, I'm quite new in javascript and jquery stuff...

I was wondering how I can push the clicked result of my confirmation box to my main function triggered by clicking the Press button?

```
<button class="btn">Press</button>
<div id="box" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <button class="modal-btn-confirm">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var confirmQuestion = function(result) {
    var resultA = [];
    $('#box').modal('show');

    function result(){
        $('#box').find('.modal-btn-confirm').on('click', function(e) {
            resultA.push(true);
            $(this).modal('hide');
        });          
    }
    if(result){
        return result(); 
    }
}

$('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
    confirmQuestion(function(result){
       if(result){
           //code ok
       }else{
           //code not ok
       }  
    });
});
```

Thanks much!

Comment: I don't understand your questions. Do you mean: `result(resultA)`?

Comment: yes trying to put result(resultA) as answer for confirmQuestion... ^^' don't know if possible...

Comment: As I understand it, on click 'Press' btn you can show confirm dialog, then for .modal-btn-confirm add event listener and continue your func

Comment: yes @Mike this is it

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, on 'Press' btn click - opens modal, then on click 'ok' push result to 'resultA' array

```js
var confirmQuestion = function() {
    $('#box').modal('show');
}

$('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
    confirmQuestion();
});
 var resultA = [];
$('.modal-btn-confirm').on('click', function(e) {
  resultA.push(true);
  console.log(resultA)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
<button class="btn">Press</button>
<div id="box" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Cancel</a>
    <button class="modal-btn-confirm">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```